# Windows 7 Gpupdate failed

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I tried to run gpupdate on a local machine but I keep getting the failed error message

I have tried following

- Remove from domain and re-add it again
- Check the dns setting all correct (Even release and renew the ip address)
- Run windows Update
- Run SFC
- Run Reg clean
- Clear old profiles

But still i get this error message. Please see below.

```
C:\Users\user>gpupdate /force
Updating Policy...

User Policy Update Failed.
Computer Policy Update Failed.

To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html f
rom the command line to access information about Group Policy results.
```

Comment: Did you review the event log? Did it shed any light?

Comment: nothing showing in event logs and even when i run gpresult /h i get this message  INFO: The user "RENISHAW\user" does not have RSOP data.

Comment: I would error message in your comment first as that is probably the culprit. It sounds like you have corrupted GPO objects.